# GIT: How to delete all Hotfix and Feature branches, and keep Development, Releases and Master - automatically?

Tags: git

As a way to organize my repositories, I would like to know how to run either a command or script to delete all Hotfix and Feature branches only. I intend to do this once they are not useful anymore. These branches will sometimes be used on both local and remote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***For the safety of the branches in your repo, please read the entire answer.***

I'm going to assume that all your feature or hotfix branches have feature or hotfix in the name.  The command to delete all of them would be the following

```
git branch -D `git branch | grep -E '(hotfix|feature)'`
```

***HOWEVER,*** before you run that, run

```
git branch | grep -E '(hotfix|feature)'
```

This command will tell you exactly which branches are going to be deleted.    Only after you are satisfied with the output of this, should you run the first command above.

Comment: For writing scripts, you should use `git for-each-ref` (a "plumbing" command, designed to work well with scripts) rather than `git branch` (a "porcelain" command, designed to be human-friendly and computer-hostile, although some would argue that the design was a failure :-) ).  Using `for-each-ref` does require that you spell out the branch name space, `refs/heads`, and so on, though.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. `git branch | grep -E '(hotfix)' | xargs -n 1 git branch -D`